# Usage of 'in vogue'

Tags: british-english

Is *in vogue* a commonly used phrase in the UK?

Background:
The famous Med School book *Davidson's Principles and Practice of Medicine* contains the phrase at least once. A med school book is an unusual place for such a phrase to be used in. The reason why I wonder about the usage of the phrase in the UK is that all the three people who authored the book are from Edinburgh.

Comment: [Senior rabbi: "Anti-Semitism is back in vogue"](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/av/world-europe-46813719)

Answer (score 1):

91 hits in the British National Corpus. The Corpus of Contemporary American is four times larger and has 430 hits. So it seems to be about equally used on both sides of the Atlantic.

Answer (score 1):

I would think it comes actually from old French where *« vogue »* designates impulsion of a boat. This word is no more used except in the expression *« en vogue »*, and in the verb *« voguer »* which means “to sail”

Answer (score 0):

The OED gives its etymology as French - indicating its meaning as "rowing" i.e a boat. It then goes on to describe a series of senses in which it is used - including the terms *in vogue*, *out of vogue* etc meaning in or out of fashion.

But the OED does not seem to supply a connection (far from obvious) between rowing and fashion. Hachette's dictionary includes the verb *voguer* - which it translates as "to sail"!

The feminine noun *vogue* is used almost exactly as it is in English  - as in *en vogue* meaning "in fashion".